# Why there is more digital money than physical money?

Tags: money-supply, paper-money

Seeing this charts:  http://money.visualcapitalist.com/worlds-money-markets-one-visualization-2017/ (also in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhI72CFrqEk&feature=emb_logo)
I cannot understand why there is more digital money than physical money.

Is this because of the stock market? but in that case, is that value real or meaningful? because if there are only $100 in physical money, and you say Facebook is worth $200, then what happen if you want to sell it, how can somebody pays $200 if there are only $100 in the world?

Comment: Think about your own situation - how much physical cash do you have versus non-physical wealth?

Comment: Being "digital" doesn't make money not real. It's also important to differentiate between currency ("digital" or physical) and other tangible or intangible things that have value (i.e. Facebook).

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without writing a treatise on currency and banking. Have you done any research? What have you learned so far, and how much of modern banking systems do you understand? Giving us some context about what you currently understand will help us fill in the gaps versus trying to explain from the ground up.

Answer (score 4):

There may be more eloquent answers that reference banking system (fractional reserves) and monetary policy, but pragmatically I would say because there doesn't *need* to be enough physical currency to represent the sum total of everyone's wealth.  Think about yourself - how much physical currency do you have compared to your total wealth? Most likely it's a very small percentage of your overall wealth. The rest is "representative" wealth like bank accounts, stocks, and other investments, plus other possessions like real estate, cars, collectibles, etc.

> if there are only $100 in physical money, and you say Facebook is worth $200, then what happen if you want to sell it, how can somebody pays $200 if there are only $100 in the world?

Because the person buying it is not using physical currency - they're probably just transferring "money" from their account to yours. But the *value* that someone is willing to give to Facebook stock is no less real.  In this case it's probably a brokerage account, but the same could be said for purchasing, say, a car. Unless you buy a car with stacks of cash, you either are writing a check or doing some kind of electronic transfer to move the money from your account to the car seller's.

Also, if you look further down the page you link and compare the "stock market" to the "global money supply" (which includes paper currency but also liquid bank accounts) you'll see much less of a discrepancy.

Comment: I have more money in my bank, but the money I have was printed first by the central bank right? and those bill should be in my bank right? and I could go to the ATM and extract them.

Comment: @Enrique - Generally, no.  Banks have way more money in deposits than they have in physical cash.  You can withdraw physical cash from an ATM but if everyone tried to withdraw all their money in cash from a bank at the same time, they wouldn't be able to (that's a bank run).  One reason that countries generally guarantee deposits in banks is to prevent bank runs.

Comment: @Enrique: Suppose you make $1000 a week.  Every Friday your employer does a direct deposit to your bank account, so no physical cash involved.  Every month you pay your mortgage from that account, so no physical cash involved.  During the month, you have various expenses, which you mostly pay with credit cards, and pay them from the account at the end of the billing cycle.  Again, no physical cash involved.  The only physical cash is the couple of hundred bucks you got from the ATM, no?  (And the money you deposit doesn't just stay in the bank, it gets invested.)

Comment: Yes but what confuses me is that in the initial point of that chain, real money should be involved right? I mean my employer send me $1000, ok where those $1000 comes from? (and follow that question until the first step of the chain)

Comment: @Enrique They got it from their customers' bank accounts, of course. Sometimes customers withdraw cash from their bank account and then give it to your employer who deposits it into theirs - same thing.

Comment: @user253751 and the customer's bank account? I think you get the point, I receive $100 from A, A received that from B, B from C, etc, but some point some person Z should have received that money in bills right?

Comment: @Enrique Nope! Banks can make up money out of thin air. The only reason they can do that is because we treat bank deposits as money. If we only treated cash as money, then they couldn't do that. Your $1000 in your bank account is not like having $1000 cash, it's a bit more like having $1000 worth of shares in the bank, but with less risk (both up and down). If you have a lot of money in the bank, you will find that they won't let you withdraw it all at once. E.g. mine has a strict €20000/month limit for cash withdrawals and €2000/day.